# User Folder Access Control

Tags: 7, users

I work at a university that has switched to Drupal. We have several hundred departments making their own "sites" in our system. Most departments need to be able to upload and change ONLY their own pdf files, images, and documents.

We can make folders for departments but no user will want to scroll through the list to upload something each and every time.

Can a folder system of some sort tie in to individual users or groups?

Answer (score 1):

> [IMCE](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce) is an image/file uploader and browser that supports personal
>   directories and quota.

You'll need to integrate this file browser with your WYSIWYG editor (supports almost every editor), and you can work with personal or shared folders for users or permissions per directory.

Comment: Consider extending your answer to explain WHY, and add "some" more details about what that module is about (not everybody may know that ...). doing so might cause your answer to no longer show up in the "low quality posts" review queue ... Just trying to help, ok? ... instead of hitting the "recommend deletion" button in that review queue ...

Comment: yes sorry you're right. I was kind of in a fast answer mode ;)

Comment: Much better! BTW, you don't have any idea about using it together with module 'og' or 'group'?

Comment: not really into og, but via permissions this should be somehow manageable i guess